# Why Cast SSLServerSocketFactory again?

Tags: java, sslsocketfactory

Why do we have to cast ssl factory instance to the same class when getting a socket factory?i.e

```
SSLSocketFactory factory = (SSLSocketFactory)SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
```

Why not do it this way?Doesnt the `getDefault()` not return an instance of the class?

```
SSLSocketFactory factory = SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because the `getDefault` method of SSLSocketFactory doesn't return a `SSLSocketFactory`, but a `SocketFactory`.

Have a look at the return type of the `getDefault` method here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocketFactory.html

Comment: Thanks Stephen, for correcting. A small but essential typo on my end!